# Fade in object ray visibility WITHOUT using alpha

Tags: materials, objects, visibility

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers solve my problem.

Here's my problem:

I have one (initially hidden through ticking off Camera in the visibility section) object that's affecting a different object with its color and material properties (it has some transmission, some color, some shadow, all of those things are affecting this other object).

[image]

**Failed attempts:**

1. **Alpha:** If I use alpha to animate, I change the way in which it colors this separate object, which I don't want. I also change the properties of the material as it fades in which I don't want.
2. **Duplicate object:** If I duplicate the object, have one with Camera turned off in the visibility window and one that's turned on (because I want to fade it in at a later point), and fade in the original (one without a check in the "Camera" visibility section) using alpha and transmission while fading out the other object (one with a check in the "Camera" visibility section) using alpha and transmission, that's closer but there's still an issue.

The issue is that the duplicated object now interacts with the original object (making it darker) ***even after*** alpha = 0, and transmission = 0. I'd like it to be completely gone and have no effect on other objects at this point. If ***after*** both alpha and transmission, I animate an ***abrupt*** tick-off of "Camera" in the visibility section, that will be undesirable, I don't want an abrupt shift like that.

3. **Transparent BSDF + Mix shader:** If I create a mix shader, and connect a transparent BSDF to the other connector, as well as the original material, and try to fade in the original material with just one object, again this removes the effect the material has on other objects when it's fully transparent. The other issue is that the object is much brighter halfway through the mixing for some reason (as though you used Add or Multiply or something) which is undesirable.

Therefore, it would be MUCH easier, if there was simply a slider to control the "Camera" visibility of an object.

I would prefer ***not*** to use view layers and multiple render times as this would be a high resolution render of an animation that would cost me cloud compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I understood the question correctly you want something like the option *Ray Visibility* > *Camera* instead of being switched on/off to gradually fade in/out. Maybe the *Transparent BSDF* and *Mix Shader* idea isn't that bad. Try the following:

As a mix factor between the normal object's material and the *Transparent BSDF* use the *Light Path* > *Is Camera Ray* node. This way the object affects others in the scene but doesn't show in camera. The *Is Camera Ray* value you can multiply by 0 with a *Math* node, then animate the multiplier from 0 to 1. This way the object fades out in camera view.

[image: light path multiplier]

This is an example of the result I'm getting with this setup. Nothing getting much brighter inbetween, as you mention in the question. However this might be dependent on the original material you're using. But I guess in your setup, where the object gets really transparent, this could be a reason while in this setup it only gets transparent for the camera.

[image: camera fade]

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! I honestly did not think one could get this close. Thank you so so much! I think the only thing missing for me is that I do have a light inside of the original object (which has some transmission and a lot of roughness). I noticed that while fading in the object using your method, the light inside of it is visible as though there was no roughness on the original object. I wish the roughness effect of the light was retained. Do you know if it's possible to use Light Paths to do that?

Comment: I think I can get around this by fading in the light after the object has faded in but was curious if that roughness effect could be retained.

Comment: Hm now I'm faced with a different problem entirely. This looks perfect in the viewport, but when I render as soon as it starts fading in from the transparent bsdf, the object is completely black and then fades to the original material. How did you manage to render it?

Comment: @Hmm I simply rendered it... maybe I should have asked this earlier since you don't mention it in the question: are you trying to render in _Cycles_ or _Eevee_? I did this in _Cycles_ and to be honest, I think _Eevee_ isn't very great when it comes to transmissive materials, so maybe fading transparency might be even more of a problem...?

Comment: Ah okay... I'm not sure what's wrong in this case. I'm using Cycles, blender 3.2. I'm using a value of 1 on the Multiply with transparency node at the bottom. As soon as it's under one (so something like 0.8 or something), it goes completely black

Comment: @Hmm Could you upload a file or something? Usually the _Material Preview_ goes black where it's supposed to be completely transparent because _Viewport Display_ > _Blend Mode_ is by default set to _Opaque_... but what you describe makes it go black when it's switching from transparent to no longer transparent. Very strange.

Comment: Sadly my file is way too big, like 700 MB. I'll try to see if I can create a reduced version to upload. My material looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/B8MWwxU.png

Comment: @Hmm The material looks okay. I mean, it's basically mine with a few differences, but changing those in my object don't change how it works. My _Multiply_ node isn't clamped, but that makes no change either. Strange. Could you maybe save a copy of the file with everything deleted except the object with the material? I just want to make sure if it's not the material that all other scene settings and object properties are the same.

Comment: Okay I managed to get it down to 2 MB by deleting everything else: https://blend-exchange.com/b/bKpBLv8a

Comment: @Hmm Okay, so it seems the different settings make a big difference in mixing. It looks like the fact that your material isn't completely transmissive and has a high transimission roughness is making the problems... I'm sorry, it seems my solution isn't working for slightly transmissive materials.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138576/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-hmm).